# Loop through all inner elements of HTML and check if field is required

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a complex multipage form using HTML, Bootstrap and JavaScript.

What I'm trying to figure out is to validate each section of the multipage form and check if all required fields (if any) are actually valid so that the user can proceed to next section in the form.

The following code snippet is a simplification of my modified form:

```
<div class="card">
    <form id="myform">
        <div class="card-body">
             <div class="section-1">
                 <div class="field-1">
                     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
                     <input required id="input-field-1">
                 </div>
                 <div class="field-2">
                     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
                     <select required id="input-field-2">
                 </div>
                 <div class="field-3">
                     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
                     <div class="nested NODE">
                          <input required id="input-field-3">
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="field-4">
                     <fieldset>...</fieldset>
                     <div class="nested NODE">
                          <div class="really nested NODE">
                               <div class="very big nested NODE">
                                     <input required id="input-field-4">
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

What is the most efficient way of getting all required fields? For now I'm iterating through each item in the section-1 and get the inner parts to check validity. But using my code below, it will not work on complex nested nodes. How to prevent that?

```
function find("required", section_number) {
    let elements = document.getElementById("form_section_" + section_number);
    let children = document.getElementById("form_section_" + section_number).children;
    
    console.log(children);
    
    for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
        
        console.log(children[i].childNodes.length);
        if(children[i].childNodes.length == 0){
            
            if (children[i].childNodes.required) {
                console.log('✅ element is required');
            } else {
                console.log('⛔️ element is not required');
            }
            
        }
        else{
            for(var y=0; y<children[i].childNodes.length; y++){
                console.log("inner loop = " + i + ":" + y);             
                if (children[i].childNodes[y].required) {
                    console.log('✅ element is required');
                } else {
                    console.log('⛔️ element is not required');
                }

            }   
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please make it an html + javascript snippet? That way I can run it and make a copy in my answer and add edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check if your form is valid, use `checkValidity()`. If you want some custom handling, you could try selecting all the possible fields and then loop over them to validate the field individually.

For instance: (this list is not complete)

```
document.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');
```

Comment: Hi @SimonGemmel, thanks for you answer. This could work but I have 120 fields in this form. Is it possible to get all these fields (`document.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');`) but only those under `field-1`,`field-2`,`field-3`,`field-4`?

I want to check in sections not the entire form

Comment: If you're not really familiar with `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, you can just use any valid CSS selector here. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for more info.

In your case, you could use `document.querySelectorAll('.field-1 input, .field-1 select, .field-1 textarea');` and so on, but this will be a pretty long selector.

Comment: A different solution could be to just loop over all inputs, and check if they have a parent that you have defined. If they are in sequence, you could even exit the loop when you encounter a child without one of those parents.

Use `.closest()` if you want to check if there is a parent with a certain class.

Comment: No need. I found the solution based on your initial suggestion:
`let array = document.getElementById("field-1").querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');`